# 0.5 TB SQL Server Database, is it possible to store in a standalone server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, storage, sql, query, big-data

We are facing the task  of storing of **0.5 TB** of data in a **SQL Server 2008 Server**.
Is it possible to do it in a **standalone server**?
Later we also want to query for generating statistics of the data (a lot of group bys, inner joins, etc) but the database is so simple(1 big table & 3 very smalls).
What you, experts, would recommend?
Do you think we will get an acceptable query response?

The specifications of the server is:

- Dedicated one
- VMWare
- 2gb of RAM
- Xeon 2.13Ghz

Comment: Only you can define what 'acceptable' means but a server like that should cope with hosting a database like you describe. As Chopper says, it's perfectly possible but I seriously would pop more memory into the server.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do it in a standalone server

Yes, but you don't talk about performance/load requirements, that said I'd pop in a bit more memory if you can, it's cheap enough these days.

Comment: the load will not be too much, only for querying for statisitcis some times per day. 30 queries per hour and it will be a lot of "group by" commands cause they are for getting statistics.